# Extjs: in TabPanel, how to put a checkbox in each tab's header?

Tags: extjs, checkbox, click, tabpanel

it seems very straight forward, but after a lot of tries and online searching, still no luck with it.

environment:
ExtJS 3.4

here is a jsfiddle I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/v4ZzT/8/

```
new Ext.TabPanel({
    renderTo: 'tab-with-chkbox',
    activeTab: 0,
    items:[
        {
            title: '<input type="checkbox"> Disabled?</input>',
            html: 'Sample panel'
        }
    ]
});
```

but that checkbox doesn't respond to click.

also found this link on sencha forum: 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?114794-Checkbox-in-tab-header
it recommends changing iconCls. but I couldn't find a way to detect if this icon is clicked or not.

Comment: I had a similar issue (place combobox in the tab's ear). You can check how it was done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589420/how-to-place-combobox-in-the-tabs-title).

Comment: thanks. i did check it out. but doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **input box gets checked**, **however** the tab panel **event handler redraws the title** after handling the click  event. You will need to **modify the** click **event handler** for the TabPanel in order **to change the title** being drawn, although a little messy you can do something like this:

```
findTargets: function (e) {
    var item = null,
        itemEl = e.getTarget('li:not(.x-tab-edge)', this.strip),
        input = e.getTarget('input');

    if (itemEl) {
        item = this.getComponent(itemEl.id.split(this.idDelimiter)[1]);
        if (input) {
            var inputEl = Ext.get(input),
                isChecked = inputEl.getAttribute('checked');
            if (isChecked) {
                item = this.getComponent(itemEl.id.split(this.idDelimiter)[1]);
                item.setTitle(item.title);
            } else {
                inputEl.dom.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }

        if (item.disabled) {
            return {
                close: null,
                item: null,
                el: null
            };
        }
    }
    return {
        close: e.getTarget('.x-tab-strip-close', this.strip),
        item: item,
        el: itemEl
    };
}
```

[**Here's a working sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/YBQ9Z/1/) based on your code, hope it helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var tabContainer = tabPanel.getAt(0);
    var customTitle = "hello";

    tabContainer.tab.on('click', function(el,event) {

      var target = event.target;
      if( target.type == "checkbox" ) {

        // If checkbox has just been checked
        if( event.target.checked ) {
          tabContainer.setTitle( '<input type="checkbox" checked />' + customTitle );
          tabContainer.checked = true;
        // If checkbox has just been unchecked
        } else {
          tabContainer.setTitle( '<input type="checkbox" />' + customTitle );
          tabContainer.checked = false;
        }
      }
    });
```